# Questions about how to Prerequisite my application properly in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, package, prerequisites

`I know there are other questions, but they have not helped me. I have some specific questions.`

1) When I Prerequisite my application, I use `The same location as my application` option. I have downloaded the Package from the `Package.xml` but I was wondering where do I put it? In a specific folder in Projects or where?

2) When it creates the `Setup.exe` can I just give them that and it will install it automatically with all the files?

3) Can I use ClickOnce with it? Because when using it, I get errors. And when not using it I do not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your 3rd question, but:

1) For Visual Studio 2013 it ought to be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\<Packagename>
```

If you are using a language other than the default (e.g. french), you need to place it in a subdirectory of the above for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\<Packagename>\fr
```

2) No, you still need to provide the package as well.  I believe you're just automating the process of installing the package if it is missing.

3) I'm not sure, but you should be able to?